# Display a view in _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have followed this tutorial to generate a dynamic list menu http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.se/2014/06/how-to-create-treeview-with-database-data-mvc4-aspnet.html

This is the view

```
@model List<Project.Models.Treeview>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Simple";
}

<h2>Simple Treeview from Database Data</h2>
<div style="border:solid 1px black; padding:10px; background-color:#FAFAFA">
    <div class="treeview">
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            <ul>
                @Treeview.GetTreeView(Model, Model.FirstOrDefault().ParentCategoryID)
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@* Here We need some Jquery code for make this treeview collapsible *@
@section Scripts{
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
                $(".collapsible").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).toggleClass("collapse-tree expand-tree");
                    $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
         }
```

And it works fine but instead of having it in a separate view I want to integrate it it my main manu. I want to display the result from the view above in the code below where I have the text "Display here".
_Layout.cshtml

```
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
Display here!!
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Video", "Index", "Video")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Photos", "Index", "Photos")</li>
</ul>
<div>
```

I have looked into Partial View and Html.RenderAction but don't know what to use

**Edit**

File structure

```
Controllers
-- TreeviewsController.cs

Models
-- Treeview.cs

Views
Shared
-- _Layout

Treeviews
-- Index.cshtml
-- Create.chhtml
-- Delete.chhtml
```

Tested with

```
<li>@{Html.RenderPartial("Index", "Treeviews");}</li>
<li>@{Html.RenderPartial("Treeviews");}</li>
```

Renamed the file from index (in views Treevviews) to `_Treeviews`

```
<li>@{Html.RenderPartial("_Treeviews");}</li>
```

Comment: You need to use `@Html.Action("Index", "Treeviews")` or `@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Treeviews") }` which calls the `Index()` method of `TreeviewsController` and renders its partial view.  Note you may also want to decorate the `Index()` method with `[ChildActionOnly]` so the partial cannot be called directly from the browser

Comment: I get this error when I use that An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code "Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'xxx.Models.LoginViewModel'."

Comment: That makes no sense - the model in the view is `@model List<Treeview>`, not `LoginViewModel` so your obviously calling something else. In any case that error could only occur if you use `Html.Partial()`, not `@Html.Action()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways to render partial views

- ***Html.RenderPartial*** - Faster that *`Html.Partial`*
- ***Html.Partial***

Use `@{Html.RenderPartial("_partialViewName")}` to render the partial view

Comment: I get the error message that it can't find my partial view. I have updated my question with file structure and this I tried. Do I need to change something in the treeview.cshtml or controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Html.RenderPartial("YourTreeViewName")` method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492503(v=vs.118).aspx